# Referencing properties of an object's parent class from inside the child object

Tags: typescript

Suppose I have four tabs to display in an Angular component, each with its own rule for whether to display it. Here's a very abstract depiction of the situation.

```
export class View {
  foo: true;
  bar: false;
  tabs: {
    'A': { order: 1, get isVisible() { return this.foo; } },
    'B': { order: 2, get isVisible() { return !this.bar; } },
    'C': { order: 3, get isVisible() { return this.foo && this.bar; } },
    'D': { order: 4, get isVisible() { return !this.foo || this.bar; } }
  };
};
```

This doesn't work because `this` refers to the `tabs` object, not to the View object that contains it. But the criteria for display the respective tabs depend on properties of the View object.

I figured this is a better and more maintainable way to organize my tabs than defining the properties directly inside the View in this manner:

```
export class View {
  foo: true;
  bar: false;
  get isTabAVisible() { return this.foo; }
  get isTabBVisible() { return !this.bar; }
  // etc.
```

Is there a way to organize this to get the outcome I'm looking for?

Answer (score 1):

Any time you come across a situation where the natural approach doesn't fit the programming paradigm, it's time to re-evaluate whether you are using the correct one (either the approach needs to change to fit the paradigm, or the you need to pick a paradigm that works with your approach). Isn't this arguably better:

```
type TabState = {
  foo: boolean
  bar: boolean
}

const state: TabState = {
  foo: true,
  bar: false,
}

enum TabOrder {
  A,
  B,
  C,
  D,
}

type Tab = {
  order: TabOrder
}

const isVisible = ({ foo, bar }: TabState, tab: Tab): boolean => {
  switch (tab.order) {
    case TabOrder.A: return foo;
    case TabOrder.B: return bar;
    case TabOrder.C: return foo && bar;
    case TabOrder.D: return !foo || bar;
  }
}
```

[Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?ssl=29&ssc=2&pln=1&pc=1#code/C4TwDgpgBAKghgIwMrDsaBeKBvAUFKAMwHtiAuKBUgGwjgDt9K4AnCq42h3AX11wDGxegGdgUMWggV4yVOihY8BEuSjAWAVwgAaJglYVCcaiN29+EepoC2sRAHkWAEwgscTAIJ6CAIR9QAMIBACJ6fLigkPYIih4ExC5uMo5JLBaCwmJQAJYiAGp5OQi0cQAU2ESkOszuPClyUjWoCA0AlOw0dPSKAHzxEgDuOcACABZQZS0AdImuLG0DBAJwZjFO89OeFCwQwJosPaoA3EzLq9CyG27Tvjt7Bz0GLKcE52tXadOB9-uHVcQoAAyIG1V5vFYfVKbEK-R5QACEqigAB8UWCmHw+EA)

This is easier to test (pure function of only it's arguments), well-typed, easier to debug, etc. etc. I know the received wisdom is that OO is well-suited for UI work, that doesn't mean the received wisdom is correct. Note that if you're locked in to OO by a framework or the existing codebase you can always make it a static method of the class.

Comment: This is well organized and, yes, OO has been beaten into me for so long that I continue to feel like everything should be is-a, has-a and composition. The only problem I have with this is the practical one which is that in the HTML template, I was looking to base the display of each tab on `*ngIf="tabs['A'].isVisible"`, for example, and that requires the *ngIf predicate to be a field or property. If I use `*ngIf="isVisible('A')"`, with a method call, the visibility of a tab won't change when the underlying values do. Any thoughts on that?

Comment: Hmmm... I think you are going to make `Tab` a class that takes a reference to the the `View` instance in the constructor rather than using POJOs. Then you can define the getter on the tabs easily because it will be `this.view.foo` instead of `this.foo`. A lot more verbose, but given the constraints probably the best option.

Answer (score 0):

You're starting off by defining a class, but then switches to a syntax of an object literal. Beside the code being invalid, I think that confusion is part of the problem - a class isn't an object, it's a set of instructions for creating an object.

If we first fix the syntax of your first snippet, it would look like this:

```js
export class View {
    foo = true
    bar = false
    tabs = {
      'A': { order: 1, get isVisible() { return this.foo; } },
      'B': { order: 2, get isVisible() { return !this.bar; } },
      'C': { order: 3, get isVisible() { return this.foo && this.bar; } },
      'D': { order: 4, get isVisible() { return !this.foo || this.bar; } }
    }
  };
```

After doing that, we can switch to use an explicit constructor in order to get a reference to the object being constructed, and use it inside the constructed methods:

```js
export class View {
    foo = true
    bar = false
    tabs

    constructor() {
      const _this = this;
      this.tabs = {
        'A': { order: 1, get isVisible() { return _this.foo; } },
        'B': { order: 2, get isVisible() { return !_this.bar; } },
        'C': { order: 3, get isVisible() { return _this.foo && _this.bar; } },
        'D': { order: 4, get isVisible() { return !_this.foo || _this.bar; } }
      }
    }
  };
```

When an object instance would be created by `new View()`, the methods that would be created under the `tabs` field would reference the properties of the new object.